# JupyterNotebook exporting graphs as SVG unintentionally cropped

Tags: python, jupyter

Within JupyterNotebook the graphs are perfectly rendered and look great, however I cannot figure out why it's (unintentially) cropping my graphs during the exporting, such that the axis descriptions are partly missing in the SVG file. Could anyone give me pointer why that might happen?

Example of a confusion matrix:

```
confusion_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, test_pred_decision_tree)
matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix)
ax = plt.axes()
sns.set(font_scale=1.3)
plt.figure(figsize=(50,25))
sns.heatmap(matrix_df, annot=True, fmt="g", ax=ax, cmap="bone")
ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix')
ax.set_xlabel("Predicted label", fontsize =15)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_ylabel("True label", fontsize=15)
ax.set_yticklabels(list(labels), rotation = 0)
fig = ax.figure
fig.savefig('confusion_matrix.svg', format="svg", facecolor=fig.get_facecolor()
```

[Confusion Matrix exported result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erloz.jpg)

Comment: try calling fig.tight_layout() before saving the image

Comment: Calling the fig.tight_layout() before saving the image solved this issue, much appreciated, thanks!